# Auto click on link/ad after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used auto click code on my site with simple code and it worked. Below is the code which I used previously.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) list[i].click();
});
</script>

<div>
<a href="#" target="_top" class="link">CLick</a>
</div>
```

But this time my code is little complicated. I was thinking: is it possible to auto-click the ad, which is created after running of the ad script code? Below is the somewhat same html part of the ad or please check the actual html on http://www.meansim.com/adtest.html

```
<div>
<div id="ac_152518">
<div class="ac_header_title">What Others Are Reading</div>
<div class="ac_adbox"><div class="ac_adbox_inner">
<div class="ac_container">
<a class="ac_image_link" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href='xyz.com">
<img height="250" width="300" src="abc.jpg" class="ac_image">
</a>
</div></div></div></div></div>
```

I just want to auto-click the "ac_image_link" href element on the page load.
P.S: I am not doing this for earning $$ just to satisfy myself that it is possible or not.

Answer (score 2):

are you still using jQuery? If yes, same as in your first example, when the document is ready:

```
$('.ac_image_link').click();
```

or

```
$('.ac_image_link').trigger("click");
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Be ensure that your AdBlocker is **disabled**, because your element gets immediately eliminated if enabled. For your situation, use this approach:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var link = $('.ac_image_link').attr('href');
      window.location.href = link;
    });
```

or if it is a static link:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
});
```

Hope it works now :)

Comment: I have like no knowledge of java. I just search and copy/paste the code.
Should I add this code in <head> as 
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ac_image_link').click();
</script>
And it will work?

Comment: you have a typo in: href='xyz.com" single and double quote aren't the same in HTML. use -> href="xyz.com"

Comment: that is not the actual code, it was just manually written here. The actual code run via javascript ad code. You can check the mentioned site's  page-source and inspect element to understand the case actually.

Comment: you have to adjust the element, because there is no '.ac_image_link' element on your site. Guess you want the element 'contentad152518' to be clicked after the page load, right? write: $('#contentad152518').click();

Comment: Check the <DIV> before 'contentad152518'

Comment: i can't see it on http://www.meansim.com/adtest.html - it's hard to help without the full code snippet

Comment: It is like this:
<div>
<div id="ac_152518">
<div class="ac_header_title">What Others Are Reading</div>
<div class="ac_adbox"><div class="ac_adbox_inner">
<div class="ac_container">
<a class="ac_image_link" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href='xyz.com">
<img height="250" width="300" src="abc.jpg" class="ac_image">
</a>
</div></div></div></div></div>

Anyways thanks a lot buddy :)

Comment: try out update 2... or simply insert the url for the link variable with quotes ;)

Comment: it is really awesome way to fetch the url in variable and than execute it. But still it is not working. it redirects to to abc.com/undefined. Maybe there is something missing or any other way to find the child element "ac_image_link" . Already given u a lot of trouble :P

Comment: redirects to "abc.com/undefined" ? look it up in your code where you find this text, since we use this string never in our snippet. And as long as it redirects you, our code here is working.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I mean to say it redirect to http://www.meansim.com/undefined as it does not find the href element.

Comment: I really don't know what could help you. Seems like .ac_image_link has no attribute "href" so the variable "link" stays undefined and it redirects you to /undefined.  It's hard to find a solution since i don't have the full code, hope you can figure it out by yourself, good luck :)